# Select where user bought every year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a `sales` table in which I store every sales. This table has columns like `year_ordered`, `userId`, `orderId` etc.

I wish to write a SQL query to select rows, where user has ordered every year from 2008.
So I only want those who have been loyal and ordered from 2008 till 2014.

I have tried with this query, but it give me anything where the `year_ordered` is greater than 2007 -

```
select COUNT(*) as sales_count, ss.userID, ss.year_ordered 
from subscriber_sub ss
where ss.date_deleted is null
and ss.year_ordered > 2007
group by ss.year_ordered, ss.userID
having  COUNT(*) > 1 
order by ss.year_ordered
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you strive for is called relational division. There are basically two ways to accomplish that:

```
select COUNT(distinct ss.year_ordered) as sales_count, ss.userID 
from subscriber_sub ss
where ss.date_deleted is null
  and ss.year_ordered > 2007
group by ss.userID
having  COUNT(distinct ss.year_ordered) >= ( select 2014 - 2008 )
```

The other way is to rewrite FORALL x : p(x) <=> NOT EXISTS x : NOT p(x), i.e. users where it does not exist a year such that there is no sale that year. I'll leave that as an exercise :-)

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your answers. This one works for me

Answer (score 2):

Try this for your `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ss.year_ordered)) = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

this should give a list of subscriber records of users that bought more than one items from 2007 to ...

```
select s2.* 
from subscriber_sub s2
where s2.year_ordered > 2007
and s2.userID in
(
    select ss.userID
    from subscriber_sub ss
    where ss.date_deleted is null
    and ss.year_ordered > 2007
    group by ss.userID
    having  COUNT(*) > 1 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work dynamically, i.e. keep working out the number of years that a user must have made an order based on the current datetime:

```
DECLARE @subscriber_sub TABLE (
    userId INT,
    year_ordered INT,
    date_deleted DATE);
INSERT INTO @subscriber_sub VALUES (1, 2007, NULL);
INSERT INTO @subscriber_sub VALUES (1, 2008, NULL);
INSERT INTO @subscriber_sub VALUES (1, 2009, NULL);
INSERT INTO @subscriber_sub VALUES (1, 2010, NULL);
INSERT INTO @subscriber_sub VALUES (1, 2011, NULL);
INSERT INTO @subscriber_sub VALUES (1, 2012, NULL);
INSERT INTO @subscriber_sub VALUES (1, 2013, NULL);
INSERT INTO @subscriber_sub VALUES (1, 2014, NULL);
INSERT INTO @subscriber_sub VALUES (2, 2007, NULL);
INSERT INTO @subscriber_sub VALUES (2, 2008, NULL);
INSERT INTO @subscriber_sub VALUES (2, 2009, NULL);
INSERT INTO @subscriber_sub VALUES (2, 2010, NULL);
INSERT INTO @subscriber_sub VALUES (2, 2011, NULL);
INSERT INTO @subscriber_sub VALUES (2, 2012, NULL);
INSERT INTO @subscriber_sub VALUES (2, 2013, NULL);

WITH YearsOrdered AS (
    SELECT
        userId,
        COUNT(DISTINCT year_ordered) AS years
    FROM
        @subscriber_sub
    WHERE
        year_ordered > 2007
        AND date_deleted IS NULL
    GROUP BY
        userId)
SELECT 
    ss.userID,
    ss.year_ordered,
    COUNT(*) AS sales_count
FROM 
    @subscriber_sub ss
    LEFT JOIN YearsOrdered yo ON yo.userId = ss.userId
WHERE 
    ss.date_deleted IS NULL
    AND ss.year_ordered > 2007
    AND yo.years = DATEDIFF(YEAR, '20070101', GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
    ss.year_ordered,
    ss.userID
ORDER BY 
    ss.year_ordered,
    ss.userId;
```

When I tested User#1 was reported but User#2 wasn't as they haven't ordered in 2014 yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know only users then you need to select`userId` with count of distinct `year_ordered` values = 7 (from 2008 to 2014 including):

```
select COUNT(*) as sales_count, ss.userID
from subscriber_sub ss
where ss.date_deleted is null
and ss.year_ordered > 2007
group by ss.userID
having  COUNT( DISTINCT ss.year_ordered) = 7
```